# Export Get-ACL to CSV with Path

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm using PowerShell 4 and have created a script that takes the shares listed in a text file and outputs ACL info to a CSV file.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to have the export include the folder path as well.  Here is my script:

```
$InputFile = "C:\Folders.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\FolderPermissions.csv"
$FolderList = Get-Content $InputFile

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList)
{
    $Permissions = (Get-ACL $Folder).access
    $Report += $Permissions
}

$Report | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited | Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

I have successfully added and exported it with single folders using the lines below, but as soon as I combine objects the only the column name gets exported, no values.

```
$Folder = "\\server\share"
$Name=Folder
$Permissions = (Get-ACL $Folder).access
$Permissions | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $Folder

$Permissions | Select-Object Folder,IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited | Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Solution:

Thanks again guys!  MFT's answer resolved it with a bit of tweaking.  Here is the working code with the filters I wanted.  Note that the .IsInherited filter returned incorrect data using -eq "TRUE", but worked successfully with -ne "FALSE".

```
$InputFile = "C:\Folders.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\FolderPermissions.csv"
$FolderList = Get-Content $InputFile

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderList)
{
    $Permissions = (Get-ACL $Folder).access | ForEach-Object {$_ |
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Folder -Value $Folder}
    $Report += $Permissions
}

$Report | Select-Object Folder,IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,IsInherited |
    Where {$_.Folder -ne $Null -and $_.IdentityReference -like "HARRAHS*" -and $_.IsInherited -ne "TRUE"} |
    Export-CSV $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Looks like just a typo. You store ACLs in `$Permissions` but you add member to `$Permission`.

Comment: Those were 2 mistypes during question creation.  Fixed now.

Comment: Can you provide the formatting of the input file that works with this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Adding a path property to each access list item would achieve your objective.

```
# Get access list items of the folder
$Permissions = (Get-Acl -Path $Folder).Access | 

    # Add the path property and assign its value, -PassThru so the object is assigned to $Permissions
    ForEach-Object { $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $Folder -PassThru }
```

Comment: This worked, with one caveat.  I'm testing it with a file that has 2 shares, and what it does is exports the second share ACL info at the top of the CSV without the path, then exports the information for share 1 and share 2 with the path.  I filtered the blank rows out and it now works fine.  However, it chokes when add more filters so that only domain accounts and permissions that are not inherited are exported.  Any ideas?  Here is my filter pipe: Where {$_.path -ne $null -and $_.IdentityReference -contains "HARRAHS" -and $_.IsInherited -eq "FALSE"}

Comment: Figured it out.  I changed to -like "HARRAHS*"  and -ne "TRUE" and it worked.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AKAJim do you know why you needed the identityreference?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a nicely formatted CSV

```
$Items = (Get-ChildItem "D:\" -Recurse | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | select fullname | %{$_.fullname.trim()})
$Path = "C:\temp\ACLs.csv"

$Table = @()
$Record = [ordered]@{
"Directory" = ""
"Owner" = ""
"FileSystemRights" = ""
"AccessControlType" = ""
"IdentityReference" = ""
"IsInherited" = ""
"InheritanceFlags" = ""
"PropogationFlags" = ""

}

Foreach ($Item in $Items)
{

$ACL = (Get-Acl -Path $Item)

$Record."Directory" = $ACL.path | %{$_.trimstart("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::")}
$Record."Owner" = $ACL.Owner

Foreach ($SItem in $ACL.access)
{
$Record."FileSystemRights" = $SItem.FileSystemRights
$Record."AccessControlType" = $SItem.AccessControlType
$Record."IdentityReference" = $SItem.IdentityReference
$Record."IsInherited" = $SItem.IsInherited
$Record."InheritanceFlags" = $SItem.InheritanceFlags
$Record."PropogationFlags" = $SItem.PropagationFlags


$objRecord = New-Object PSObject -property $Record
$Table += $objrecord
}
}
$Table | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation
```